# Taking screenshot of UIView which having subview with CATransform3DMakeRotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to generate screenshot of UIView which having subview with `CATransform3DMakeRotation`. Screenshot is generated but it doesn't contain Rotation.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Actual View:

[image]

ScreenShot Image

[image]

Using following call to Flip the view horizontally...

```
  currentView.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(currentView.layer.transform,CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0f));
```

Code for taking screen shot

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    CGSize screenDimensions = view.bounds.size;

    // Create a graphics context with the target size
    // (last parameter takes scale into account)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screenDimensions, NO, 0);

    // Render the view to a new context
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [view.layer renderInContext:context];

    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you’re using to actually take the screenshot. There are a couple of different mechanisms.

Comment: Updated my question with code to take the screenshot.

Comment: @Sagar on iOS 7 you could try `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:`. As far as I understand that should work.

Comment: @HAS: thanks for this info, but My application is running below iOS 7.

Comment: I seem to recall this sort of thing working on devices but not the simulator. Where are you running this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "renderInContext" only works for Affine transform. So convert the 3D transform into affine transform like this

```
currentView.layer.affineTransform = CATransform3DGetAffineTransform(CATransform3DConcat(currentView.layer.transform,CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0f)));
```

Comment: I like this answer ! I would like to add a vote, but it does not work for me ! I only changed ==>> view.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(view.layer.transform, t) TO view.layer.affineTransform = CATransform3DGetAffineTransform(CATransform3DConcat(view.layer.transform, t)) and no longer have my transformation.. I go to apple's doc.. thanks !!

Comment: the affine transform are very limited, if you want a true 3D transform you can use iOS7 [UIView drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:] instead of [CALayer renderInContext]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(yourview.frame.size.width , yourview.frame.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize,YES,2.0f);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
[yourview.layer renderInContext:context];
[yourview drawRect:yourview.frame];

UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Tried with your approach, but still not able to get proper screenshot.

Comment: Make sure the rotated view is a subview.

Comment: It seems like you have problem with frames. Check the subview frame before taking screenshot.

Comment: I found your problem. Set the anchor point before rotating. currentview.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

Comment: Yes, it is already set but I am using some other anchorPoint. seems like this api is not working with CATransform3DMakeRotation

Answer (score 1):

This might work, try it:

```
  CGRect grabRect = CGRectMake(40,40,300,200);

    //for retina displays
  if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(grabRect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
  } else {
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(grabRect.size);
  }
  CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -grabRect.origin.x, -grabRect.origin.y);
  [self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];
  UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: Tried with This.. Still same issue... It is clear that CATransform3DMakeRotation is not captured in [self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx]

Comment: You want to take screen shot of the currentView right? Then modify this in the same code: [self.currentView.layer renderInContext:ctx];

Answer (score 0):

i have achieved this in one of my application by doing a little tweak like first i capture the whole screen's screen shot and then crop it with the desired frame i need here is a sample code from my app.

```
- (UIImage *) croppedPhoto
{
    [imgcropRectangle setHidden:TRUE];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Create bitmap image from original image data,
    // using rectangle to specify desired crop area
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], self.imgcropRectangle.frame);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    [imgcropRectangle setHidden:FALSE];
    return result;
}
```

here imgcropRectangle is the UIImageView's object that defines my desired rectangle so i use it's frame for cropping from full screen to desired output. Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I need to capture the screen with Subviews having CATransform3DMakeRotation.

Comment: then instead of this line self.imgcropRectangle.frame you could put your subview's frame and use the code i've put and have a look what it results.

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering `view.layer.presentationLayer` instead of `view.layer`

Answer (score 0):

use this and before passing the view check its subviews :

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height));
        [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return viewImage
}
```